# Workflow to create a folder in the Shared Documents Library upon creation of a list item

Tags: workflow, tasks

I have a List that people create an item for new project requests. I have a workflow that notifies the Assigned To person, however I would like to also have it create a Sub Folder under the Shared Documents Library based on the Title of the request.

Maybe a Parallel process?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you googled before asking?
Have a look [here](http://www.getinthesky.com/2012/08/creating-folders-and-sub-folders-using-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflow/)

It's exactly your same scenario.

1. Create a SharePoint list workflow in List A
2. Set workflow to start automatically upon new item
3. Create a step to name variables (Looks nice and makes it easier to edit later on – optional)
4. Create variable Vcase and set the value to [%Current Item:  Title%] ([%Current Item:Id%])
5. Create variable Vsubfolder1 and set the value to Subfolder 1 (Optional but makes it easier to edit later on)
6. Create a step to create new element (This is the root folder)

   Select “DocLib” as list to create item in

   Select “Action – Create list element”

   Add “Id for contenttype” – set in to Folder

   Edit “Path and name (*)” – set it to [%Variable:Vcase%]
7. Create a step to create new element (This is the subfolder)

   Select “DocLib” as list to create item in

   Select “Action – Create list element”

   Add “Id for contenttype” – set in to Folder

   Edit “Path and name (*)” – set it to [%Variable:Vcase%]/[%Variable:Vsubfolder1 %]
8. Repeat step 5 and 7 for each subfolder you wish to create.

Comment: Yes, thank you. 

I found it about the same time you posted. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: The answer for this works fine, but if the library has an & in its title and the folder has an & in its title, the workflow stops. I have a bunch of libraries, which I use this workflow above to create a unified folder structure. It has completed for all except when an & is in the folder name. The workflow creates the first folder in the first library (the first library happens to have an & in the title) then it stops.

Answer (score 0):

You can create folder using SharePoint designer workflow by adding folder content type in list and then add action "Create list item" in workflow in which will create item using folder content type to create folder in list.

Steps are given in this [Post](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/create-folder-in-list-using-workflow/)