# Displaying different newly made folders library in webpart of a list's display form

Tags: web-part, document-library, list-form

I intend to set up a workflow that will make a folder for every new element added to the list. This folder will be a small documents library for this specific list item.

I would like to display this folder contents in a webpart alongside a display form whenever i click on the item so people can access it. However the only thing I was able to find is how to do it for a CONCRETE, predefined, single folder. But each time I will have a new, different folder made that i want displayed. How to do it? I was thinking maybe it is possible to make a dynamic/JavaScript url that will get the ID column name used for folder creation and then access the folder?

I'm using sharepoint online.

Comment: I'd re-think my architecture if I were you. I'd ask a new question with the business requirements laid out in non-technical terms and ask for guidance on how to structure the data.  Creating a folder in a workflow seems incredibly hacky and brittle.  There's probably a simpler way to do what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not that hard actually. I found a solution e.g. [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87847/workflow-to-create-a-folder-in-the-shared-documents-library-upon-creation-of-a-l)
I was thinking of just naming documents with their respective corresponding element names and than using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295448/sharepoint-how-do-i-filter-a-document-library-view-to-show-the-contents-of-a-su/6751423#6751423) to display it, but it's not that elegant, because it relies on users actually naming files like that (and you can't trust them to do so all the time)